# How to extract line 5 for example from a PDF archive like this pdfminer script?

Tags: pdfminer

```py
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io


resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

with open('ARQUIVO.pdf', 'rb') as fh:

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,
                                  caching=True,
                                  check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()

print(text)
```

Comment: You can use https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ for questions in Portuguese.  This site is for questions in English.

Comment: Also, [how to format code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Nate Eldredge, i'm completely new. If you have something to help me, I appreciate it.